# Mysql error when running Laravel php migrations

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have upload my laravel project to Ubuntu 14 i have install MySQL to the server put a try to run migrations using php artisan migrate i keep getting this error [PDOException] SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using pas sword: YES i dont understand how to fix this.

Comment: Check your password on _mysql_ try signing in with the  password you know. If it fails then that's your problem, else check your _laravel .env_ file to make sure you have the right password entered there.

Comment: the MySQL lets my in so the password good but the php migration wont work for me

Comment: check the password in the _.env_ file in laravel

Comment: Have you checked the password yet ?

Comment: Yes i have George and still nothing

Comment: it work on local machine when i am using wamp server and MySQL local instance

Comment: The check was done on the upload machine ?

Comment: yes on my Ubuntu test server and it throws that error i mention

Comment: I have check the .env files and put a password in there i have put a password in there and still it throws connection errors

Comment: what version of laravel ?

Comment: is it laravel 5.3

Comment: is the information in the _.env_ file like this: DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=database_name
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=password. And did you regenerate the _.env_ file at the upload location ?

Comment: No i did not regenerate but where DB_host is just say local host should change that to 127.0.0.1

Comment: should use composer up date

Comment: You are supposed to regenerate the _.env_ at upload location __never upload .env__ and use __composer update__ and then add __DB_HOST=127.0.0.1__ if __localhost__ doesn't work.

Comment: I git add it all should I should git check it out then copy the .env example file ? and change that

Comment: add it to the __.gitignore__ file as __.env__ then upload your work and the __.env__ will be left out then you can manipulate the __.env.example__ file, but still run __composer update__ to get a knew key __don't copy__ the old one.

Comment: thanks George i sure this is the problem i finish work soon i let you know next week if that was the problem thanks for the help i used stfp to upload and forget to put the env file in the gitignore

Comment: Ok George thanks for you help was that and the password as well php artisan worked cheers George

Comment: let me put down answer that you mark as correct, glad it worked out.

Answer (score 0):

Hi everyone thanks for the advice and help it was because i did not generate the .en file on the server and my password was wrong to so i am happy now

Answer (score 0):

According to your issue you uploaded the entire *project* including the *.env* file. In Laravel when uploading your finished work they are several things you don't do:

1. never upload the *.env* file instead regenerate a new one using *composer update*, as this will contain sensitive information that should not moved in that way.
2. use the same *application key* for both location, this will be regenerated when *composer update* is run at the new location.

Solution:

1. add the *.env* file to the *.gitignore* file so it's never seen like other files.
2. after uploading your work use the included *.env.example* file, change it to *.env* then run *composer update*. Add your database information from the new location there.
3. run `composer update` and the new *.env* file should be ok.